# php openssl_encrypt generates null value when using openssl_decrypt

Tags: php, ssl, yii, openssl

I want to encrypt a number using openssl_encrypt in Yii Framework;

I managed to encrypt the number;

When trying to decrypt the number, i get a null value;

```
class Utils {
    /*
     * variables and values used to encrypt and decrypt the cnp
     */
    public static $textToEncrypt = "My super secret information.";
    public static $encryptionMethod = "AES-256-CBC"; // AES is used by the U.S. gov't to encrypt top secret documents.
    public static $secretHash = "25c6c7ff35b9979b151f2136cd13b0ff";
    public static $options = false;//options can be one of OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING or false
    public static $iv = '1234567890123456';

}
```

this is how I encrypt the number, and this part works, as i get a result:

```
$this->user->cnp = openssl_encrypt($this->user->cnp, Utils::$encryptionMethod, Utils::$secretHash, Utils::$options, Utils::$iv);
```

This is how I decrypt, but I get a null value for the number:

```
$a = openssl_decrypt($model->cnp, Utils::$encryptionMethod, Utils::$secretHash, Utils::$options, Utils::$iv);

echo 'cnp decripted: ' . $a;
```

why don't i get the original value when using these function:

```
echo 'cnp encrypted: ' . openssl_encrypt('1850302260089', Utils::$encryptionMethod, Utils::$secretHash, Utils::$options, Utils::$iv);

echo ' cnp decripted' . openssl_decrypt('1850302260089', Utils::$encryptionMethod, Utils::$secretHash, Utils::$options, Utils::$iv);
```

Comment: Btw: Yii has a [Security Manager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#securityManager-detail) component, but I haven't verified if it fits all your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `openssl` but the value you are trying to `decrypt`

Where did you get `$model->cnp` from ??? and that is where the problem is

Try

```
$cnpData = openssl_encrypt($this->user->cnp, Utils::$encryptionMethod, Utils::$secretHash, Utils::$options, Utils::$iv);
$a = openssl_decrypt($cnpData , Utils::$encryptionMethod, Utils::$secretHash, Utils::$options, Utils::$iv);

echo 'cnp decripted: ' . $a
```

Just tested it and it works perfectly

Comment: The cnp is a unique number, each human has one; I got the number using a form; Then i got redirected to a view and I dont have access to it anymore; Now, the new cnp is $model-cnp